NServiceBus 8 with EF Core 8 outbox
I'm trying to use NServiceBus in .NET 8 with EF Core 8. It's important to get the transaction outbox working.
Specifically, this code is to setup transaction sharing. The problem is, this sample is for EF Core 7 and there is no EF Core 8 sample. In EF Core 8, UseTransaction was removed
The sample code from Particular is here:
https://docs.particular.net/samples/entity-framework-core/
endpointConfiguration.RegisterComponents(c =>
{
    c.AddScoped(b =>
    {
        var session = b.GetRequiredService<ISqlStorageSession>();

        var context = new ReceiverDataContext(new DbContextOptionsBuilder<ReceiverDataContext>()
            .UseSqlServer(session.Connection)
            .Options);

        // This is bad, UseTransaction was removed.
        context.Database.UseTransaction(session.Transaction);

        //Ensure context is flushed before the transaction is committed
        session.OnSaveChanges((s, token) => context.SaveChangesAsync(token));

        return context;
    });
});


The sample you refer to has a dropdown to d/l different versions, if you d/l the one for NServicebus 9 it does reference EF Core 8.
Also, UseTransaction is still available in EF Core 8, see
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.relationaldatabasefacadeextensions.usetransaction?view=efcore-8.0&viewFallbackFrom=net-8.0
